# Worklight application is not loading the javascript in android

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a simple application that is using plain jQuery without jQuery mobile... The application uses socket.io.js to connect to a node.js server that is hosted at the same network.

The problem is: the application runs ok in the preview, but when i put it in android then my javascript is not loaded so nothing happens.

my index.html load the javascript in this way:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

at the end of the document, close to  tag as you can see.
My main javascript is the app.js, it loads the application logic (connection, functions etc).

My doubt is: the worklight only works with jQuery mobile or Sencha touch or Dojo? i can use simple plain jQuery too? i have to make something to load my javascript in android?

when i press a button that has an action to a javascript function i receive in LogCat it:

```
10-30 17:41:22.142: I/chromium(17492): [INFO:CONSOLE(128)] "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/app.js (128)
10-30 17:41:22.144: E/NONE(17492): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at (compiled_code):128
```

But in the app.js at this line 128 just have it:

```
// TODO: verify user
```

(just a commented line)

Answer (score 0):

IBM Worklight works with any UI javascript framework (Jquery Mobile, [Sencha](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-senchatouch/), etc). Try to simplify your app or [follow the tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-jquerymobilejsontut/).

What are the lines after 128 on app.js? You can make console.log() calls to figure out what breaks.